# Компонент секундомер останавливаетсмя если бесконца обновлять состояние в родителе. React

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from 'react';
import Timer from "./Timer";
const Timer = props => {
  const {
    minutes,
    seconds
  } = props;
  const [minutesState, setMinutes] = useState(minutes);
  const [secondsState, setSeconds] = useState(seconds);
  useEffect(() => {
    let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (secondsState > 0) {
        setSeconds(secondsState - 1);
      }
      if (secondsState == 0) {
        if (minutesState == 0) {
          clearInterval(myInterval)
        } else {
          setMinutes(minutesState - 1);
          setSeconds(59);
        }
      }
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
    };
  });
  return ( <
    div > {
      minutesState === 0 && secondsState === 0 ?
      null :
        < span className = "question-statistics-count-subtext" > {
          minutesState
        }: {
          secondsState
        } <
        /span>
    } <
    /div>
  );
}

export default Timer;

class Main extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    const {
      children
    } = this.props;
    return ( <
      div className = "main" >
      <
      div className = "container" >
      <
      Timer minutes = "11"
      seconds = "59" / >
      <
      button onClick = {
        () => this.setState({
          something: "something"
        })
      } > aasdasd < /button> <
      /div> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;

ReactDOM.render(
    <Main />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите чтобы таймер не останавливался можно добавить `minutesState`, `secondsState` в массив зависимостей useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
   ...
}, [minutesState, secondsState]);
```

Можно и другие вещи исправить, непонятно что должно в итоге получиться.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло) А почему таймер останавливался если не добавлять массив?

Comment: Отлично! Из-за особенностей внутреннего устройства Реакта.